# can we build object detection model using Tensorflow or it is only possible with the help f tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is there any way to build object detection model using Tensorflow without any help of tf.keras module?

From Tensorflow documentation I'm  not able to find any example which helps to create model without Keras.

Comment: Have you heard of the TensorFlow object detection API? It is literally what you want.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I saw their documentation but it only shows training and using existing models, it does not show how to create your own model from scratch. If you have any documentation links then could you please share them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras is a high level API. But if you want to use only Tensorflow then you have to implement the architecture using low level API. You can certainly implement but you have to code it yourself to build all the convolutional layers and dense layer by yourself.

Comment: do you have any link for creating models in Tensorflow or any documentation?